# Send UDP data through C# Winform to STM32

Tags: c#, visual-studio, udp

I want to send data in array using UDP

```
                        send_buffer[0] = 10;
                        send_buffer[1] = 'b';
                        udpsend(send_buffer);
```

this is what i tried

```
        string [] send_msg1 ;
        send_msg1 = new string[20];
        send_msg1[0] = " 't' ";
        send_msg1[1] = " 8 ";

        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4");
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 80);



        byte[]  sendbuf1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(send_msg1); // getting error here
        s.SendTo(sendbuf1, ep);
```

This above code not sending in array form.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not able to send data in array form.

Comment: what is array form?. data is send as a bunch of bits

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending data by using udp.

I make a code example, which could send data and receive data successfully.

Code:

Server:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(11000);

            while (true)
            {
                var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
                var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
                udpServer.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, remoteEP); // if data is received reply letting the client know that we got his data          
            }
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000); // endpoint where server is listening
            client.Connect(ep);

            // send data
            client.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5);

            // then receive data
            var receivedData = client.Receive(ref ep);
            string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(receivedData);
            MessageBox.Show("receive data from " + ep.ToString()+"   "+data);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]